# Twisted - Simple file completed event for FTP server

Tags: python, ftp, twisted, ftp-server

I want to use twisted for some basic FTP server, [just like this example](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/attachment/ticket/1579/ftp_server_example.py):

```
from twisted.protocols.ftp  import FTPFactory, FTPRealm
from twisted.cred.portal    import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers  import AllowAnonymousAccess, FilePasswordDB
from twisted.internet       import reactor

#pass.dat looks like this:
# jeff:bozo
# grimmtooth:bozo2

p = Portal(FTPRealm('./'), (AllowAnonymousAccess(), FilePasswordDB("pass.dat")))
f = FTPFactory(p)
reactor.listenTCP(21, f)
reactor.run()
```

...with one simple customization: I want to fire an event when a file upload (STOR) is completed successfully, so that my custom code can adequately handle this file.

I found no documentation for FTPFactory or FTP that helps me doing this. Should I overload the FTP object or some other object? How to wire everything up?

I have done simple custom HTTP servers with twisted in the past and it was pleasantly easy, but I can find nearly no material about FTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this is just a modification of Rakis' answer. Without his answer this would not exist. His one just wouldn't work on my setup. It also may just be that the API has changed, since this is 5 years later.

```
class MyFTP (ftp.FTP):

    def ftp_STOR(self, path):

        d = super(MyFTP, self).ftp_STOR(path)

        def onStorComplete(d):
            print 'STORED', repr(d), path
            return d

        d.addCallback(onStorComplete)

        return d

f = ftp.FTPFactory( some_portal_object )
f.protocol = MyFTP
```

Comment: I'm unable to test this (it _has_ been 5 years), so I'm just going to believe you and accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the following may do the trick

```
from twisted.protocols import ftp

class MyFTP (ftp.FTP):
    def ftp_STOR(self, path):
        d = super(MyFTP, self).ftp_STOR(path)

        d.addCallback( lambda _: self.onStorComplete(path) )

        return d

    def onStorComplete(self, path):
        # XXX your code here

 f = ftp.FTPFactory( some_portal_object )
 f.protocol = MyFTP
```

Comment: It didn't; the callback was invoked before the file transfer started (and the transfer is looping, using Filezilla). Also, my file isn't being stored. :\

Comment: `ftp_STOR` definitely returns a Deferred that only fires after the transfer is complete.  Perhaps something else is going wrong with your program.

Comment: I based on the example I linked on my question. I'm noticing all write attempts are failing. I'll investigate this a bit further…

Comment: So apparently that example does not write to disk. :( I'm considering just waiting for the FTP api+docs to mature and just take a pooling approach.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the reason Ekevoo's example does not write to disk is because he's using `FTPRealm('./')` like ln. 36 of the example shows.  This sets the `anonymousRoot` of the `FTPRealm` class, but leaves the `userHome` value at the default of `/home` (as shown in the [source](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.1.0/twisted/protocols/ftp.py#L2141), which seems like a bad design that was [never really fixed](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4494)).

I would suggest using `FTPRealm(anonymousRoot='./', userHome='./someDir')`.

Comment: I'm also facing the problem that this doesn't fully upload the file. The server is on Linux and the client is WinSCP on Windows. When I use it without MyFTP, it works. But when I use the class as written above, the download stops at 100%, and only when I then cancel the upload the file appears on the server. There is something missing in the code above.

Comment: I had to modify the code, added it as an answer because I was not sure if it is OK to modify Rakis' code in his answer.